# How to reduce /dev/sda1 primary partition size and create new partition with it

Tags: ubuntu, storage, partition, fdisk

Hi I'm facing an issue

**OS** : Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

i have my storage set up like this :

lsblk :

```
sda       8:0    0   400G  0 disk
├─sda1    8:1    0 399.9G  0 part /
├─sda2    8:2    0   512B  0 part
├─sda14   8:14   0     4M  0 part
└─sda15   8:15   0   106M  0 part /boot/efi
```

I want to reduce the size of sda1 to create a new raw partition for rook-ceph sda3 with 100G

I have tried many solutions but i only end up breaking the filesystem and rebooting again

I hope someone can guide me to the right direction

Answer (score 0):

You can only change this while the disk is not mounted, so you cannot be booted from that disk.

I'd boot from a "live" CD such as [GRML](https://grml.org/) and then use the gparted tool from there.